Solving the Bring quintic using the Monster?
I. Method
Hermite's method to solve the Bring quintic by functions that obey $x^8+y^8=1$ implicitly uses octahedral symmetry, while Emil Jann Fiedler's solution by the Rogers-Ramanujan continued fraction $R(q)$ in this MO post uses icosahedral symmetry.
With no details from Fiedler on the latter's derivation, I've been trying to reverse-engineer it hoping that, by using different functions such as Borwein cubic theta functions which obey $x^3+y^3=1$, it will lead to the last Platonic symmetry, the tetrahedral. (Update: The Huber quintic theta functions in this post which obey $x^5+y^5=1$ can solve the Bring as well.)
Given a fifth root of unity $\zeta = e^{2\pi i/5}$, we start with the function,
$$V_n = \frac{2-\big(1-\zeta^n\, a\big)\big(1+\zeta^{2n}\, b\big)}{\zeta^{4n}}$$
Expand $\prod_{n=0}^4\big(x-V_n)$ to get,
$$x^5-5Ax^2-5Bx-C =0$$
which is in principal quintic form and where,
\begin{align}
A &= a^2 - b + a^3 b^2 + a b^3\\[4pt]
B &= a + a^4 b - 3 a^2 b^2 - b^3 - a^3 b^4\\[4pt]
C &= 1 + a^5 + 10 a^3 b + 10 a b^2 - 10 a^4 b^3 + 10 a^2 b^4 - b^5 + a^5 b^5
\end{align}
By two happy "coincidences", if $a=R(q)$ and $b=R(q^2)$, then $A = 0$ since it is the modular equation between them, while $B = \pmb\square$ is a square (to be seen later). Since $A = 0$, the quintic will be in Bring form. Scale variables $x = B^{1/4}y$ to simplify further,
$$y^5 - 5y - \frac{C}{B^{5/4}}=0$$
Equate this to a generic Bring for some free parameter $h$,
$$y^5 - 5y - h^{1/4}=0$$
and we get a system of $3$ equations in $3$ unknowns $(a,b,j)$,
\begin{align}A &=  a^2 - b + a^3 b^2 + a b^3 = 0\\[5pt]
h &= \left(\frac{C}{B^{5/4}}\right)^4 = \frac{(1 + a^5 + 10 a^3 b + 10 a b^2 - 10 a^4 b^3 + 10 a^2 b^4 - b^5 + a^5 b^5)^4}{(a + a^4 b - 3 a^2 b^2 - b^3 - a^3 b^4)^5}\\[5pt]
j &=\frac{-(a^{20} - 228a^{15} + 494a^{10} + 228a^5 + 1)^3}{a^5(a^{10} + 11a^5 - 1)^5}
\end{align}
where the last is the formula for the j-function in terms of $a=R(q)$. I thought resolving this would result in a horrible mess and a $120$-deg equation in $j$ did pop up. But factored, it was just a nice quadratic in j with a multiplicity of $60$ (the order of icosahedral symmetry),
$$\Big(j^2 - (h^2 - 207h + 3456 )j + (h + 144)^3\Big)^{60}=0$$

II. Monster
The appearance of the equation,
$$j^2 - (h^2 - 207h + 3456 )j + (h + 144)^3 = 0\tag1$$
was a surprise, as the first two McKay-Thompson series of the Monster satisfy this relation,
\begin{align}
j=j_{1A}(\tau) 
&= \left(\frac{E_4(\tau)}{\eta^8(\tau)}\right)^3\\[5pt]
&= \left(\left(\frac{\eta(\tau)}{\eta(2\tau)}\right)^8+2^8 \left(\frac{\eta(2\tau)}{\eta(\tau)}\right)^{16}\right)^{\color{red}3}\\[5pt]
&= \frac{1}{q} + 744 + 196884q + 21493760q^2 +\cdots\\[7pt]
h=j_{2A}(\tau) 
&=\left(\left(\frac{\eta(\tau)}{\eta(2\tau)}\right)^{12}+2^6 \left(\frac{\eta(2\tau)}{\eta(\tau)}\right)^{12}\right)^2\\[5pt] 
&=\left(\left(\frac{\eta(\tau)\,\eta(2\tau)}{\eta\big(\frac{\tau}2\big)\,\eta(4\tau)}\right)^{4}-4 \left(\frac{\eta\big(\frac{\tau}2\big)\,\eta(4\tau)}{\eta(\tau)\,\eta(2\tau)}\right)^{4}\right)^{\color{red}4}\\[5pt]
&= \frac{1}{q} + 104 + 4372q + 96256q^2 +\cdots\\[5pt] 
\end{align}
which (without the constant term) are adjacent sequences A007240 and A007241. Note they are generally cubes and fourth powers. For example,
\begin{align}
j=j_{1A}\left(\tfrac{\sqrt{-58}}2\right) &= 30^3\big(140989 + 26163\sqrt{29}\big)^3\\[4pt]
h=j_{2A}\left(\tfrac{\sqrt{-58}}2\right) &= \,396^4
\end{align}
with the latter used in Ramanujan's famous $1/\pi$ formula. And as was mentioned earlier, if $a=R(q)$ and $b=R(q^2)$, then $B$ in fact is a square,
$$B = a + a^4 b - 3 a^2 b^2 - b^3 - a^3 b^4 = a^2b^2\left(\frac{\eta(\tau)\,\eta(2\tau)}{\eta(5\tau)\,\eta(10\tau)}\right)^2$$
with the eta quotient also a McKay-Thompson series, for class $10C$, or A132041.

III. Modular lambda function
To find the needed elliptic modulus $k$ and $\tau$, we use the j-function formula in terms of the modular lambda function $\lambda(\tau)$ and elliptic parameter $m=k^2$,
$$j= \frac{256(1 - m + m^2)^3}{(m - m^2)^2}$$
Substitute this into the relation between the two McKay-Thompson series $j_{1A}$ and $j_{2A}$, and it has three quartic factors in $m$. We assume $h = c^4$ and $m=k^2$ and it factors further into two quartics in $k$, the relevant one being the near-palindromic,
$$k^4+\left(\tfrac{c}2\right)^2 k^3+2k^2-\left(\tfrac{c}2\right)^2 k+1 =0$$
The discriminant $D$ of $x^5-5x+c=0$ is $D = 5^5(c^4-256)$. The quartic roots are,
$$k =\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{2}\,c-\sqrt{c^2+\sqrt{c^4-256}}}{\sqrt{2}\,c+\sqrt{c^2+\sqrt{c^4-256}}}}$$
with the first two by $\sqrt{D/5^5}=\pm\sqrt{c^4-256}$ so it seems expected that $D$ appears.

IV. Quintic solution
We now have all the information needed. Let,
$$y^5-5y+c=0$$
then the five roots $y_n$ for $n=0,1,2,3,4$ are,
$$y_n = \frac{2-\big(1-\zeta^n\, a\big)\big(1+\zeta^{2n}\,b\big)}{\pm B^{1/4}\;\zeta^{4n}}$$
where,
$$B = a + a^4 b - 3 a^2 b^2 - b^3 - a^3 b^4$$
$$\,a = R(q),\,\quad b = R(q^2)$$
$$\zeta = e^{2\pi i/5},\quad q=e^{2\pi i\tau}$$
$$\tau = \frac{K'(k)}{K(k)}\sqrt{-\frac14}=\frac{_2F_1\big(\tfrac12,\tfrac12,1,\,1-k^2\big)}{_2F_1\big(\tfrac12,\tfrac12,1,k^2\big)}\sqrt{-\frac14}$$
$$k =\tan\left(\frac14\arcsin\Big(\frac{16}{c^2}\Big)\right)$$
and $K(k)$ is the complete elliptic integral of the first kind for real $c$. (For complex $c$, one may have to use the other roots of the quartic.) It is similar to Emil Jann Fiedler's solution but with the advantage we know how it was derived. (Plus an interesting detour through the Monster along the way.)

V. Question
Can we use a function similar in form to,
$$V_n = \frac{2-\big(1-\zeta^n\, a\big)\big(1+\zeta^{2n}\, b\big)}{\zeta^{4n}}$$
where $(a,b)$ is related to Ramanujan's cubic continued fraction or the Borwein's cubic theta function to solve the Bring quintic? It would finally add the missing tetrahedral symmetry of the Platonic solids.

does the general program of "pick a 2-variable algebraic curve (ex: the circle), define arc length parametrization on it (sin and cos), then solve polynomial equations using newly defined functions" always work to eventually solve any polynomial equation? I've seen trig functions being used to solve the cubic and now this $x^8 + y^8$ parametrization seems to work on the quintic and so that motivates the question of "is solving polynomials always the same thing as parametrizing 2-variable algebraic curves"

@SidharthGhoshal Not quite that simple. The trig functions sin and cos obey $x^2+y^2 = 1$ and can be used to solve the reduced one-parameter cubic $z^3+z+\alpha=0$. The elliptic lambda function as eta quotients instead obey $x^8+y^8= 1$ and it was Hermite's insight it can be used to solve the reduced one-parameter quintic $z^5+z+\beta = 0$. There might be a possibility the Borwein cubic theta functions obeying $x^3+y^3 =1$ can do so as well, that's why I made this post. For sextics, it can be reduced to a two-parameter form but you need the two-parameter Kampé de Fériet function to solve that.

Interesting how that pattern breaks at $n=6$. It does seem like the  Kampé de Fériet functions are an extremely general class (a generalization of the hypergeometric functions). I guess then one might be instead motivated to ask "is there some algebraic surface in $\mathbb{C}^3$ which is parametrized by a collection of 2-variables functions (generalizing $\sin$ and $\cos$) that can then solve the sextic? There might be a way to make those vague statements more concrete and continue the pattern here.

@SidharthGhoshal If ever you find the answer to that question, feel free  to post it. I know almost 10 different methods to solve the quintic, but only 2 for the sextic. It seems some lost interest when Galois proved no higher formulas were coming. But Klein did interesting work for degrees $p = 5, 7, 11$.

@SidharthGhoshal I just finished checking the Borwein's cubic theta functions and $x^3+y^3=1.$ See tentative answer below. No luck so far.

I've been perusing the following papers:

"Solving the quintic by iteration" (1989).
"Icosahedral symmetry and the quintic equation" (1992).
"On Klein's icosahedral solution of the quintic" (2014).

The first mentions a tetrahedral resolvent of the quintic, the second about "partitioning it into five objects of tetrahedral symmetry", and the third "inscibes a tetrahedron in an icosahedron". So it is possible. Now if we can only find an explicit function to do it.

Please stop bumping this question with continual edits.

@HJRW My apologies, but the post was getting too long so I removed a lot of details. That was the last one, I promise. However, for the answer, I may have to do a single edit as I figured a possible solution, if that is ok?

@SidharthGhoshal I just found out that the cubic continued fraction $C(q)$ and $x^3+y^3=1$ can indeed solve the Bring quintic.  Kindly see 2nd answer to this post.

@HJRW By the way, I didn't edit the post (last edit was Nov 3). I only added a 2nd answer which finally answered the question correctly.

@TitoPiezasIII that’s friggin  awesome. I’ll be quite honest I need to learn a lot more to make sense of your work, it’s advanced for me, but I will ping you once I’m ready. These kinds of questions morally seem very interesting to me. I feel like the story never should’ve ended after Quintics were found to be non radical solvable and you are really carrying out the program of solvability further.

@SidharthGhoshal Thanks for the comments. I guess the advantage of the quintic is it can be reduced to one-parameter form, and there are a lot of one-parameter special functions (though not all will do). P.S. I've been trying to do the same to the sextic for years, but as the reduced form is two-parameter, it requires even more exotic functions. For deg-5, only the elliptic modulus $k$ needs to be derived. For deg-6, now two variables have to be derived which complicates things. So the quintic was almost within reach of solvability.

(New answer):

One approach was to express the modular lambda function $\lambda(\tau)=A^8(\tau)$ in terms of the cubic continued fraction $C(\tau)$. For example, define,
\begin{align}
A(\tau) &= \frac{\sqrt2\,\eta\big(\tfrac{\tau}2\big)\,\eta^2(2\tau)}{\eta^3(\tau)}\\[5pt]
C(\tau) &= \frac{\eta(\tau)\,\eta^3(6\tau)}{\eta(2\tau)\,\eta^3(3\tau)}\end{align}
and let $\alpha = C(\tau)$ and $\beta = C(2\tau).\,$ Then,
$$A^8(6\tau) =\frac{16(\alpha+\alpha^4)\,\beta^4}{(1-4\alpha^2\beta^2)^2}$$
However, it seemed a bit unsatisfactory.
An alternative approach was to follow Hermite. He solved the Bring quintic using a modular equation between $A(\tau)$ and $A(5\tau)$. It turns out a modular equation between $C(\tau)$ and $C(5\tau)$ can solve the Bring quintic after all.
The new solution is in this MO post as it raises questions of its own, with a familiar octic popping up. (And as usual, two McKay-Thompson series of class 6 for the Monster appear too.)


(A tentative answer using analogues of Hermite's approach.)
I've been analyzing the situation from Ramanujan's theories of elliptic functions to alternative bases of signature $(2,3,4,6)$. Hermite's solution of the Bring quintic seem to depend on properties peculiar to signature $2$.

I. Signature 2 and $\color{blue}{x^8+y^8 = 1}$
Given the Dedekind eta function $\eta(\tau)$. Then,
$$\left(\frac{\sqrt2\,\eta(\tau)\,\eta^2(4\tau)}{\eta^3(2\tau)}\right)^8+\left(\frac{\eta^2(\tau)\,\eta(4\tau)}{\eta^3(2\tau)}\right)^8 = 1$$
which is equivalent to the Jacobi theta functions,
$$\left(\frac{\vartheta_2(0,q)}{\vartheta_3(0,q)}\right)^4+\left(\frac{\vartheta_4(0,q)}{\vartheta_3(0,q)}\right)^4 = 1$$
Define $A(\tau) =\dfrac{\sqrt2\,\eta(\tau)\,\eta^2(4\tau)}{\eta^3(2\tau)}.$ The modular relation between $A(5\tau)$ and $A(\tau)$ is a sextic,
$$u^6 - v^6 + 5u^2v^2(u^2 - v^2) + 4u v(1 - u^4v^4)=0$$
If $v = A(\tau)$, then the six roots $u$ are,
$$-u = -A(5\tau),\;A\big(\tfrac{\tau}{5}\big),\;A\big(\tfrac{\tau+16}{5}\big),\;A\big(\tfrac{\tau+32}{5}\big),\;A\big(\tfrac{\tau+48}{5}\big),\;A\big(\tfrac{\tau+64}{5}\big)$$
These $u$ can be used to solve the Bring quintic. Define the function,
$$\alpha(\tau) = \Big({-A(5\tau)}-A\big(\tfrac{\tau}{5}\big)\Big) \left(A\big(\tfrac{\tau+m}{5}\big)-A\big(\tfrac{\tau+4m}{5}\big)\right) \left(A\big(\tfrac{\tau+2m}{5}\big)-A\big(\tfrac{\tau+3m}{5}\big)\right)$$
for $\color{blue}{m=16}$. Then expanding,
$$\prod_{n=0}^4\big(x-\alpha(\tau+n)\big)= x^5+c_1x+c_2 = 0$$
Three coefficients vanish and where the $c_i$ are expressions in terms of $A(\tau)$. Equating to a generic Bring, one can then find $\tau$. But the situation is different for signature $3$.

II. Signature 3 and $\color{blue}{x^3+y^3 = 1}$
We have,
$$\left(\frac{3}{\left(\frac{\eta(\tau/3)}{\eta(3\tau)}\right)^3+3}\right)^3+\left(\frac{\left(\frac{\eta(\tau)}{\eta(9\tau)}\right)^3}{\left(\frac{\eta(\tau)}{\eta(9\tau)}\right)^3+9}\right)^3=1$$
which is equivalent to the Borweins' cubic theta identity,
$$\left(\frac{c(q)}{a(q)}\right)^3+\left(\frac{b(q)}{a(q)}\right)^3 = 1$$
Define $B(\tau) = \dfrac{3}{\left(\frac{\eta(\tau/3)}{\eta(3\tau)}\right)^3+3}$. The relation between $B(5\tau)$ and $B(\tau)$ is again a sextic,
$$(u^3 - 1)(v^3 - 1)(u^3 + 75 u v + 330 u^2 v^2 + v^3 + 321 u^3 v^3 + 1) - (1 - u v)^6 = 0$$
If $v = B(\tau)$, then the six roots $u$ are,
$$u = B(5\tau),\;B\big(\tfrac{\tau}{5}\big),\;B\big(\tfrac{\tau+3}{5}\big),\;B\big(\tfrac{\tau+6}{5}\big),\;B\big(\tfrac{\tau+9}{5}\big),\;B\big(\tfrac{\tau+12}{5}\big)$$
Let,
$$\beta(\tau) = \Big(B(5\tau)-B\big(\tfrac{\tau}{5}\big)\Big) \left(B\big(\tfrac{\tau+m}{5}\big)-B\big(\tfrac{\tau+4m}{5}\big)\right) \left(B\big(\tfrac{\tau+2m}{5}\big)-B\big(\tfrac{\tau+3m}{5}\big)\right)$$
for $\color{blue}{m=3}$. Then expanding,
$$\prod_{n=0}^4\big(x-\beta(\tau+n)\big)= x^5+c_1x^3+c_2x+c_3 = 0$$
Only two coefficients vanish (after experimenting with various sign combinations). It is worse for signature $4$.

III. Signature 4 and $\color{blue}{x^2+y^2 = 1}$
We have,
$$\left(\frac{8}{\left(\frac{\eta(\tau/2)}{\eta(2\tau)}\right)^8+8}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\left(\frac{\eta(\tau)}{\eta(4\tau)}\right)^8}{\left(\frac{\eta(\tau)}{\eta(4\tau)}\right)^8+32}\right)^2=1$$
Define $C(\tau) = \dfrac{8}{\left(\frac{\eta(\tau/2)}{\eta(2\tau)}\right)^8+8}$. The relation between $C(5\tau)$ and $C(\tau)$ is still a sextic.
Since the sextic $P(u,v)=0$ is long, suffice to say that if $v = C(\tau)$, then the six roots $u$ are,
$$u = C(5\tau),\;C\big(\tfrac{\tau}{5}\big),\;C\big(\tfrac{\tau+24}{5}\big),\;C\big(\tfrac{\tau+48}{5}\big),\;C\big(\tfrac{\tau+72}{5}\big),\;C\big(\tfrac{\tau+96}{5}\big)$$
Define,
$$\gamma(\tau) = \Big({-C(5\tau)}-C\big(\tfrac{\tau}{5}\big)\Big) \left(C\big(\tfrac{\tau+m}{5}\big)-C\big(\tfrac{\tau+4m}{5}\big)\right) \left(C\big(\tfrac{\tau+2m}{5}\big)\color{blue}{+}C\big(\tfrac{\tau+3m}{5}\big)\right)$$
for $\color{blue}{m=24}$. Then expanding,
$$\prod_{n=0}^4\big(x-\gamma(\tau+n)\big)= x^5+c_1x^3+c_2x^2+c_3x+c_4 = 0$$
Now only one coefficient vanishes (after experimenting with various sign combinations). I didn't bother with signature $6$.

IV. Some remarks
In summary, using the functions $A(\tau),\,B(\tau),\,C(\tau)$, we can construct quintics where three, two, or just one coefficient(s) vanishes, respectively. So it makes the $A(\tau)$ of signature $2$ "special" since it attains the Bring form. However, there are other functions, but that's for another post. (For more context, this MO post might be informative.)

V. Tetrahedral symmetry
(As the question looks for a function associated with tetrahedral symmetry, there are some promising leads, but the research is still in progress.)
